# How to have a tkinter button destroy/quit the root window in a nested function?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7

I'm trying to have it so that when a tkinter button is pressed, a value is assigned, and then the gui is exited.

My problem is that root.quit has no effect from functions other than the one that called it, even nested functions.

Code:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Button
def buttonDialogWindow():
    root = Tk()
    def buttonPress(isHeadArg):
        #Do something
        root.quit

    Button(root, text='Front of String', command = buttonPress(1)).pack()
    Button(root, text='Back of String', command = buttonPress(0)).pack()
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.quit)
    root.mainloop()
buttonDialogWindow()
```

Running the code makes the buttons appear. Clicking them has no effect on the GUI, and the mainloop does not exit.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

The problem was that when I set the value of command, I was calling the function rather than declaring it. Using parentheses made the function get called -- if you have no parameters, the normal way to write this would be to write

`command = buttonPress`

If you do have parameters, I found a workaround using lambda: my code currently has

`command = lambda: buttonPress(1)`

for the commands.